# computer (windows XP) doesn't want to open .py

Tags: python, windows

I'm a beginning programmer in Python and I have a strange problem with my computer. When I have a .py file on my computer (containing a script that works), and I double click on it to open, the following happens: the program opens (it's the black screen view), but it shuts itself down within a second, and the program isn't executed. However, when I right click and choose "edit with IDLE", everything works as normal.

I didn't have this problem from the beginning on, but then I installed some other versions of Python and I think that's the moment when scripts didn't want to open anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that there has been an association with the `py` extension and it probably is running your program, but it is closing too quickly for you to see any output. You can add a wait or just open a command prompt and run everything from there.

Another solution, and in my opinion the more ideal one, is to set the association of the `py` extension to IDLE. This would solve your issue as the file will open by default in IDLE and from there you can run the Python script.

[Changing File Associations In Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! You were right that the program is being executed. When I open a program that requires user input, it doesn't shut down immediately.

I tried to change the association to IDLE, but strangely I can only find the shortcut to the program in my computer, and not the program itself... 

A last question: how do I run a script from the command prompt? When I type python test.py it doesn't work (test.py exists on my computer), although I read here (http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) that this is the way to do this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You probably don't have to have the `python` binary on your system path. [Using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) has instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I added python as a system variable (C:\Python27), but when I enter `python test.py` in the command line, it still says SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Does this have anything to do with the python binary or is it caused by something else? Sorry for all the questions...

Comment: There is a syntax error in the python script itself, but the python binary appears to be working fine.

Comment: The python script contains no syntax error, it only consists of `print("Hello.")`?
But the command line says File "<stdin>", line 1, python test.py, SyntaxError: invalid syntax. 
Sorry if I don't understand what you meant!

Answer (score 2):

> but it shuts itself down within a second, and the program isn't executed.

Yes, the program is being executed. It is being executed so quickly that you don't have a chance to see what is happening.

Put `raw_input()` at the end of your code so that the console window doesn't close instantly.

Comment: Thank you, that works! But why is it executed so quickly now, whereas this wasn't the case before? It doesn't make sense to me because no one is able to see his/her program executed this way...?

Comment: @Johanna If it isn't executed inside IDLE and it doesn't ask for input or do any heavy computations, it will appear to finish instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Austin is right, you made a console app, and once its finished(in microseconds), it closes itself.

Create a mainloop or use Austin's trick, to force app not to close itself.